# Setting a specific day in the date powershell

Tags: powershell

I am creating an automated script to generate a new one year client secret for Azure apps and want to set the EndDateTime for the client secret to always be the first of the month one year from the end date for consistency.
Example, the client secret for an app ends on 8/15/2022.
When I run the following script to create a new client secret, I'd like the end date to be 9/1/2023 ( one year later and the first day of the following month)

```
$pwCred=@{
"EndDateTime"=(Get-Date).AddDays(365) #  <-- want this to be day 1 of the next month 1 year from the enddatetime
"displayName"="Test Auto Cert2" 
}

$Secret = Add-MgApplicationPassword -ApplicationId XYZ-XYZ-XYZ-XYZ -PasswordCredential $pwCred
```

Comment: Can you show your complete script? Do you have the “end date” as a variable? Which format?

Comment: EndDateTime = Sunday, August 7, 2022 4:00:00 AM

Comment: To get the first day of the next month you take the first day of this month and use `().AddMonth(1)`.   ... and there is a method `().AddYears()` as well. ;-)

Comment: .Addmonth(1) will not set the month to the first day of the month.

Comment: If you use the first day of this month it will. ;-)

Comment: Not sure what you mean? can you give an example?

Comment: You can see the example down here ... ↓  ;-)

Comment: Keep in mind that `Get-Date` does not return just a date, but a full timestamp (i.e. with current time). You might want to take that into consideration.

Comment: ... and you can circumvent this by using the `().Date` property. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just an example ...

```
$GivenDate = Get-Date -Day 11 -Month 12 -Year 2022
$FirstOfNextMonth = $GivenDate.AddDays(- $GivenDate.Day + 1 ).AddMonths(1)
$FirstOfNextMonthNextYear = $FirstOfNextMonth.AddYears(1)

$GivenDate
$FirstOfNextMonth
$FirstOfNextMonthNextYear
```

Comment: Nicely done; the only thing worth adding is that if the given date's day already is the first of its month, you may not want to add a month (depending on the specific requirements).

Comment: Thanks.  You're always the one thinking a step further than everybody else. ;-)  This special condition should be checked then with an if statement by Chabango I think.   ¯\_(ツ)_/¯